# Insets not respected

Tags: java, swing, gtk, cross-platform, insets

I'm writing a calendar panel to use in an application. To display days I use JButtons. Since I don't want the buttons to take a lot of space they have no insets.

Here is how it looks in my GTK+:

[image]

All buttons are displayed nice and clean.

Now here is how things look when I switch to the Metal laf:

[image]

Simply said, this isn't acceptable.

When I set the insets by putting `setMargins(new insets(0,0,0,0))` in the constructor of the custom button all works and it looks like I want it to look.

[image]

Now those buttons aren't the only buttons affected in a negative way and I don't feel like I should set this everywhere manually so I need a cleaner solution.
I've tried setting the default button margin through `UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));` but this didn't affect anything.
This is driving me nuts, and I don't know how this affects other lafs like Aqua or Windows laf but I fear the worst.

Edit:
Just tested it in Windows XP and guess what:

[image]

Edit2:
The Main() creates and shows this frame. It has several components on it who are created by `initComponents()`. The `initComponents()` was created by Netbeans and it has a `pack()` at the end.

```
public class MainForm
    extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        String laf = null;
        if (os.contains("win"))
        {
            laf = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel";
        }
        else if (os.contains("nix") || os.contains("nux"))
        {
            laf = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel";
        }
        else if (os.contains("mac"))
        {
            laf = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel";
        }
        try
        {
            UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
            System.out.println(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        initComponents();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the UIManager to set the Button.margin works fine for me on XP using JDK6_7. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right I solved my issue and of course it was actually quite simple, here it comes.
The buttons I use in my calendar panel are `JToggleButton`s. The "Button.margin" only applies to `JButton`s. So all I needed to do was to add 1 line:
`UIManager.put("ToggleButton.margin", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));`

A list of items you can set in the `UIManager` can be found [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/JavaUIDefaults.txt).